# Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer cannot use with Fiddler

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fiddler, owin

I tried to use `TestServer` and found that Fiddler could not catch the traffic.

The address is set to `http://localhost` and no way to change it.

```
        server = TestServer.Create(app =>
        {
            new Startup().Configuration(app);
        });
```

It would be good to change the url to `http://ipv4.fiddler` or some other candidate methods in http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/observe-traffic/troubleshooting/notraffictolocalhost page.

how can I do?

Comment: Fiddler could not catch *what* traffic? What's the client in this scenario?

Comment: @EricLaw // Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer seems to fix its host address to `http://localhost`. Is there any way to change the hosted address? Fiddler cannot catch `localhost`.

Comment: "Fiddler cannot catch localhost" is inaccurate. Please answer my questions.

Comment: @EricLaw // Just all traffics from-and-to hosted `TestServer` during the unit test. As you know, Fiddler cannot monitor `http://localhost` so I want to know how to change the hosted address or workaround settings to monitor `localhost` with Fiddler.

Comment: The client example is described in http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2014-01-12-integration-testing-katana-with-auth.html page. A general example to use with `TestServer`.

Comment: Of course Fiddler can monitor `http://localhost`. The trouble you have is that *.NET* bypasses the proxy for that hostname, which is why you change the *client* to use `localhost.fiddler`. The server doesn't change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work as `TestServer` fakes out the transport layer and just creates and passes in HttpContext objects to your controllers.  There's no traffic for Fiddler to intercept and no real *TCP* or *HTTP* performed.