# How to Debug a Post to an OWIN Service?

Tags: c#, web-services, owin, middleware

I have an OWIN self host service.

Another service (which I dont have access to) is POSTing data to it over a local network IP address (though computer name gives same results).

The problem I have is that the value is always 'null' in the controller.

I've tried fiddler, but [cannot see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058358/microsoft-owin-testing-testserver-cannot-use-with-fiddler) any traffic. I know it is sending correct data, as another service (which I also cannot see) is definitely getting something.

From the appBuilder.Use() statement, I know the service is definitely being hit and it will navigate to the controller.

How can I find out what's wrong or does anyone know what is going wrong please?

Setup

```
public void OWINWebServerConfiguration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            appBuilder.Use(async (environment, next) =>
            {
                //NOTE: Post will definitely hit this but I can't find the content of the message

                Debug.WriteLine(environment.Request.Uri);
                await next();
                Debug.WriteLine(environment.Response.StatusCode);
            });

            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            // IMPORTANT - ENABLE UNITY TO TAKE CONTROL OVER DI
            config.DependencyResolver = new Helpers.UnityResolver(_unityContainer);


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{content}",
                defaults: new { content = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(OWINConfig.AllowedAccessUrls, "*", "*");
        //config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"));
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(FormCollection fc)
{

    //fc, will be null. Changing the signature means the controller will not be hit.
    HttpResponseMessage response;

   // if (value != null)
    //    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "ID:", value);

    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK");

    return response;
}
```

Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try using a [FormDataCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.formdatacollection(v=vs.118).aspx)?

Comment: No, but I will give that a try when I get a chance. Thanks.